# My Windows 10 Computer Randomly Shuts Down

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

After 20 minutes or so of being powered on and used, this HP Beats Windows 10 (AMD Core Processor) shuts down for no apparent reason.

I'm not certain where to look to find an explanation or the cause of this problem such as log files so I'm looking for some help with this.

I get very frustrated and I'm not sure where to start to troubleshoot or what to do for a solution.

Comment: You must read [How to ask a good question ?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Get a can of compressed air and with the laptop powered off, try blowing into the areas of the enclosure to blow out any caked dust which may be restricting air flow. If it's clogged with dust, etc. and air cannot flow to keep it from overheating, it may power off automatically to prevent further damage to internal components. It may just be overheating and powering down due to this but more detail may be helpful as well.

Comment: You should probably reconsider the tone of your question if you want help. And add more details about your issue while you are at it.

Comment: Second LMFAO_A_JOKE's answer--this is very likely a cooling issue.  Clean out the dust, make sure all fans are spinning.  (Note that with a laptop they may turn on and off based on temperature.  That's not a problem.)  Computers have a thermometer in them, if it goes too high the system turns off right then.  Cursing an unexpected shutdown is a lot better than cursing a machine that fried itself instead of shutting down.

Comment: If there's no explanation why you ask for one?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504/en-us

Comment: Mine has this problem ... in a VMWare virtual machine. Ruling out hardware.

Comment: @frumbert how is that possible?

Comment: @ewnr I second frumbert's assessment.  There are several potential causes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a long time ago! But i will post a solution to this... Basically, the problem was first. Make sure you have the HP Coolant System on in the task manager processes . That was one of the issues. Next take a long at your advanced options in battery power options:

[image]

Make sure you have the same options as i have in power options. This solution is mostly if you hear loud sounds from your computer when it is processing tasks. If this is not the case , you mostly have either a problem with windows itself or your computer is not in clean condition. First, try out `user267838` answer . If that doesn't work , reinstalling windows will surely work . Don't worry data won't be lost just since you reinstalled the OS. Hope this helped!

Comment: On my Toshiba, there's a "TOSHIBA Power Saver Settings", under which there is Cooling Method, which can be set to "Cooling Optimized". For me, it was set to "Maximum Performance" for both battery and plugged in, instead. Reading this post lead me to trying that. Setting the CPU to 80% max isn't a bad idea, either, as just running any Internet Browser seems to spike the CPU and probably causing a lot of heat with the activity. Neither of these solved my problem, though.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a hardware problem, but before such conclusion can be drawn, we must troubleshoot the problem to avoid unnecessary replacement of hardware components.

The best place to start is by asking windows why it decided to shut down.
Most likely Windows doesn't know either (if the hardware malfunctioned, windows didn't trigger the shutdown itself)
But if Windows knows what happened, it can be of great help.
unfortunately, at this time I also don't know where exactly this information can be found. I hope other super users can point that out.
There are probably a few error logs we can look at, however I don't know which that would be or where they would be, so I hope someone else can post about that.

Now we can also troubleshoot the hardware a bit.
sometimes a computer shuts-down suddenly to prevent damage from overheating.
Often, one can set a temperature value in the BIOS at which the computer should shut down.
You could start by holding your hand next to your PC where the air is blown out, and felling if it seems unusually hot. If it does, there is a change your PC is overheating. If it feels somewhat cool, maybe the fan is not even working, or there simply is no overheating.
A more direct approach would be to download software like HW Monitor from CPUID. This software can tell you much about the temperature of your hardware and sometimes also about the fans. There is a freeware version which can do the trick.

We could also be dealing with faulty memory (RAM). You can download and install a program called memtest86+ for this (I recommend the memtest86+ over memtest86, yes there is a difference)
This software is directly installed on an empty USB flash drive. the drive is than bootable, which means you have to reboot your PC, and load the software from the flash drive to run before windows starts.
If you run memtest86+, it will simply test your memory and report any errors found (if there are any).
If your memory is indeed faulty, it most likely needs to be replaced.

this are only some random attempts to troubleshoot the problem. It is very hard to give a fitting answer to your question without more information about the problem.

Comment: I know my answer goes all over the place and doesn't provide the necessary detail at this time. However, the question also lacks the necessary information, and this answer might provide a starting point to diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Troubleshooting problems are a poor fit for the site because they often cannot be answered as-is other than by a guess.  The responses tend to be an open-ended series of diagnostic suggestions and helpful hints, which should appropriately be done in comments since answers are intended to be solutions.

Comment: Yea my computer overheats. How do i fix problem

Comment: @fixer1234 I agree with you, and I learned something. But it was the easiest way to provide a large amount of startingpoints without needing several comments (which have a character limitation) But yes I agree, I will use comments for this next time.

Comment: @ewrwr If your computer overheats, the main solution would be to prevent the computer from overheating again. Most often, the computer overheats because dust has build up near the fans or between the metal cooling blocks. If there is any dust, this needs to be cleaned out. You can do this with a can of compressed air, by blowing the dust away. Be careful not to blow it further into the cooling block. Let us know if this solved your problem. If this solves your problem I will post this as the answer to your question.

Comment: Ultimately, if your computer still shuts down, you could go into the BIOS setup, and change the temperature at which the computer will shut down. However, this should be considered more or less a last resort, as this shutdown is mealy a failsafe to prevent the computer from truly overheating and burning out. If you do decide to change the temperature at which the PC shuts down, only put this value slightly higher (5 degrees). Sometimes that can solve the problem, allowing the computer to get hot, but not yet too hot. A computer which gets this hot usually has a significant problem with cooling

Comment: @ewrwr Most computer hardware shops offer to clean your PC for you, if you don't want to do this yourself. If you are hesitant to do this yourself, in fear of damaging your computer, you can look for a hardware shop nearby and ask them if they offer this service.

Comment: @StaticStorm for some reason when i put my computer in an elevated (like my desk) place it does fine. But im worrying that wont last for long :( . And when i blow the place where it heats with my mouse it actually shuts down by it self...

Comment: @ewrwr That definitely sounds like your PC is just on the edge of the safety shutdown. Please blow out any dust first. You will probably need to open the computer up to properly clean it. If the computer still overheats when it is clean, you can go into the BIOS settings and see if you can change the shutdown temperature.   Your computer should always be on a flat surface which allows it to suck up air and blow out air without obstruction. Some laptops suck or blow air at the bottom, which can get blocked if you put them on a bed or on a carpet.

Comment: @StaticStorm but i cant take off the computer by my self. And i cant tell my dad , he will kill me. Idk what to do i need help.

Comment: @ewrwr If your PC is just dusty that doesn't sound like it is your fault. You should be able to just ask your father to have a look at it. It doesn't sound like you caused this issue, it just happens. Not clearing your computer can eventually lead to more overheating, so it is better to act on it now. Please do not attempt to do it yourself if you are not experienced with this. You wouldn't want to cause damage to your computer. Your father might be able to clean it, or he could bring the computer to a shop where they clean it for you.

Comment: @StaticStorm i will think about it. I dont know really.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. Took me weeks and a fair amount of money to figure it out, having replaced power supply and mainboard. I guess the takeaway here is never assume anything.

The computer is used in an air conditioned room, not overclocked, and has a zillion fans in the case, so I assumed overheating was not the problem until I booted to the BIOS and monitored the temperature. Watched it go up to over 90 C. This photo tells it all.

[image: Dirty heatsink]

This was not obvious from a casual look at the APU. After cleaning, the temp went down to 56 C and stayed there.

Answer (score 3):

## Review the Windows System Logs

This can be done by a **Start Menu** search for **Computer Management**. Within the **Computer Management** window, expand *System Tools* **>** *Event Viewer* **>** *Windows Logs* **>** *System* then scroll through until you find an *Error* event - this should be a red (!). Review these *Error* events which will provide reasons as to why the system crashed.

A recent example is one of my PCs was crashing and the logs indicated that firmware changes had occurred while in transition between sleep states. The device continued to crash and cause HDD issues. A *checkdisk* was completed with a reboot and all working fine now :).

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a common problem with the new Window 10 upgrade. Try this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDWtGC5VbEM

Video suggests to disable Fast Startup which can be found in Control Panel at "Power Options" > "Choose what the power button does"

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: This happened a long ago.. And i saw this viedo before, so i fixed this a long time ago.. These days, this computer sometimes goes off(rare), but thats if i put it on my lap(when i get very tired), which will eventually heat the computer and shut down safely. Thanks for the anwser though!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is NOT always a hardware/cooling issue.  I, myself, did not have this issue until I upgraded to Windows 10.  I found several potential causes:

1. Windows 10 introduced something I've seen referred to as a "Hybrid shutdown".  Apparently this causes shutdown problems with Windows, and can be disabled by:

Windows menu > Settings > System > Power & sleep > Additional power settings >
Choose what the power button does > Change settings that are currently unavailable > Scroll down to the Shutdown settings : uncheck Fast Startup.

2. On the Power Options page, find your power plan and select Change plan settings.  When plugged in, change the settings to "Never".  Select to change advanced power settings.  Under "Hard disk", change "Turn hard disk off after" to 0, which should change it to "Never".  Select "Sleep".  Change "Sleep after" to 0, which should change it to "Never".  Under "Allow hybrid sleep", select "Off".  Change "Hibernate after" to "Never".
3. You may have Windows Updates automatically updating, and then restarting your PC.  In your Windows Updates section, change it to ask you before restarting:  Settings > Update & Security > Advanced options > Notify to schedule restart

On this same page, select View your update history.  You may find, like I did, several failed update installs.  I found they derived from the KD3210721 Windows 10 Cumulative Update.  If you click on one of the "Failed on MM/DD/YYYY" links and then click "More info" on the resulting pop-up, you can get to the page with that individual update and download it.  When I did this, I arrived at a page with "Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 Update History" and "Updates for Windows 10 Version 1511", which had several dates - the top (latest) of which was [January 10, 2017—KB3210721 (OS Build 10586.753)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009939).  At the bottom was a link to get the standalone installer from [the Microsoft Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB3210721) for the full cumulative update, where there was a Download button for the update.

4. A Microsoft rep advised this could happen as a result of corrupt system files.  I had some odd errors in my System Event Log (accessible by Windows key + R, then typing compmgmt.msc).  So I ran `sfc /scannow`.  This may help some.
5. I had errors related to an Intel MEI driver.  I re-downloaded and re-installed it from https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26146/Intel-Management-Engine-Driver-1-5M-for-Windows-10-for-Intel-NUC-D54250WYK-B-and-D34010WYK-B -- this may help some, but should confirm you have the error in your Event Log before doing so.  I did not have any exclamation point on the driver in my Driver Manager, just the Event Log warnings "LMS cannot connect to Intel(R) MEI driver". They didn't go away after doing this re-installation, though, so I don't know if it might still be a culprit.

Reference:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3LzlBMPswg

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on 2 HP notebooks, 8770w and 8540w, with Windows 10 Pro. I opened both notebooks and cleaned them thoroughly. All dust has been removed and the fans are clean and working. I also cleaned the cooling areas for CPU and GPU and put new cooling gel between CPU and GPU and the heatsinks. Furthermore I bought 2 external cooling fans and put them under the notebooks.
At first the notebooks did work fine but still they got warm although no excessive processor use was seen in the resource monitor. As a result I got the event 41 for the Kernel-Power with the message "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed or lost power unexpectedly."

Finally I decided to change the power plan when plugged in:
turn off the display after 30 min.; put the computer to sleep never.

After 30 min. the screen went blank (as meant to be) but the system began to start the fan and got warmer and warmer. As a result the notebook shut down and in the event log event 41 was again logged.

I now changed the power plan when plugged in:
turn off the display never; put the computer to sleep never.

As a result of this the fan was not started and the system did not get warm. At the end of the day I closed the notebook lid but letting the notebook still operate to let the automatic do its work during the night. The notebook was still working fine the next day and no critical events (41) were logged.

So, I could solve this unwanted random shut down by setting "turn off display = never"  and setting "put computer to sleep = never" when plugged in. The system does not get warm abnormally anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To solve my apparently random shutdowns of a new Windows 10 laptop, I went to:
control panel > Power options > Change plan settings > Change Advanced.. > Sleep node > Hibernate after.. > to 'never'

Ha cha!