# Laptop randomly shuts down after latest Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, laptop, shutdown, power

Since the latest update of Windows 10 my computer decides to randomly shut down after every couple of minutes. First the screen goes black, then the sounds stops and after quite a while the power also goes down.

Obviously I though of cleaning the fan with a big vacuum, as suggested on [My Windows 10 Computer Randomly Shuts Down](https://superuser.com/questions/1021267/my-windows-10-computer-randomly-shuts-down) . However, after doing this, the shutting down goes even quicker. I cannot even properly log-on before the shutdown takes place.

What should be my next step?

Ps. The computer is quited aged (roughly 3 - 4 years). The battery is dead enough such that I always need to have it plugged in an outlet. It might just be "done for" but I'm hoping to revive it for just a little bit more.

Comment: I think it's a heat problem. If so, you may need to (re)apply thermal paste, open up the fan, etc. If you manage to run it for at least a couple of minutes you should install a temperature monitor program.

Comment: You should boot into the BIOS and just keep it running there. See if it crashes there too. This will determine if its a hardware or software problem. If it runs fine in the BIOS, then its a software problem, and you likely need to reinstall windows.

Comment: @TNierath I was able to install a tempetature sensor. It is all around 40-50 degrees, which seems about right. Next step is checkin the Bios indeed

Comment: If you haven't done so already I'd also put the machine under load (video compression, game?) and observe the temperature. It's possible that it remains cool when it does next to nothing but quickly reaches the critical point when busy.

Comment: @TNierath I just notice that my message was incomplete. I was streaming video's and it remained 40-50 and it still shuts down. I need to check the Bios to see if lpchip's steps help identify the problem.

Comment: @LPChip I booted the computer in BIOS and indeed, the laptop didn't shut down. I will have a look at reïnstalling soon. Thanks for tips the both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get in to the event log before the shutdown occurs?
If so, do you get errors when you filter the Windows logs > System on the following event IDs: 1074, 6006, 6008?

Also, since the issue you describe started manifesting itself after the major update on W10, i'd say something went wrong there. You could do a rollback to the previous version of W10 via System Setting > Update & Security > Recovery.

If that doesn't help, it'd probably is due a hardware malfunction